# how do I perform addition within a concatenated string?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to append a `<style>` element to the `<head>`.

I have a variable set to `150`. I want to add `5` to that var number and then include it in a string I append to the DOM. The result would be `155px`

I tried these with no luck:

```
var divWidth = 150;

$("head").append("<style>div{width:" + divWidth + 5 + "px}</style>");
$("head").append("<style>div{width:" + divWidth + " + 5px}</style>");
$("head").append("<style>div{width:" + divWidth + " + 5 + px}</style>");
```

Comment: Correct way is ```divWidth = `${parseInt (divWidth) + 5}px`; ```

Comment: Is this JS or CSS? If it's JS you need to fix the syntax as it's completely invalid, if it's CSS what you're trying to do isn't possible.

Comment: jquery , appending style to head , updated question

Comment: Thank you. That was vital information which was needed in the question

Comment: ```$("head").append("<style>div{width:`${divWidth + 5}px`}</style>");``` use this

Comment: @rory by mistake i commented wrong, now rectified

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve your goal you need to wrap the numerical values in parentheses so that the addition operation is performed on them *before* the string is concatenated together. Try this:

```js
var divWidth = 150;
$("head").append("<style>div{width:" + (divWidth + 5) + "px}</style>");
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid #C00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Lorem ipsum</div>
```

Comment: thank you !  that was going to be my next round of attempt wrapping in () , this stuff is driving me insane trying to learn , appreciate it !